# Regex – how to match and replace with javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match symbol sequence according to these rules:

1. it's located at the start of the string
2. case insensitive
3. it begins with letter `V` or `N`
4. optional space follows
5. `-` or `–` characters follows (only one of them)
6. optional space follows

Here are example strings that it should match and expression I tried to make using google results :) :

```
var str = "V - ";
/*var str = "N - ";
var str = "V- ";
var str = "N -";
var str = "N –";
var str = "V– ";*/
str.replace(/^(V|N)\s(-|–)\s/i, 'replaced'); 
alert(str);
```

However it doesn't seem to work. Can someone help me please and explain how it is used, what I did wrong? Thanks

Comment: *it begins with letter V or N* but your regex is expecting `V` or `H`, right? `(V|H|v|h)`

Comment: well right, where's your point? BTW made and edit from `(V|H|v|h)` to `(V|H)` as I discovered `/i` later

Comment: @simPod I think the point is that `N` and `H` are different letters?

Comment: ah damn! I'm learning Russian and sometimes it confuses me :D will make and edit. Thanks!

Comment: Try this regex: `/^[VN] ?[-–] ?/` [or see this demo](http://regex101.com/r/jO9iN2/1)

Comment: @anubhava that's interesting, I might even prefer yours! Also the link is great

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this regex mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Comment: possible but not actual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are so close. the `str.replace` function doesn't actually modify `str`, but it returns a modified copy of it, so what you want is

```
var str = "V - ";
/*var str = "N - ";
var str = "V- ";
var str = "N -";
var str = "N –";
var str = "V– ";*/
var str2 = str.replace(/^(V|N)\s?(-|–)\s/i, 'replaced'); 
alert(str2);
```

also, notice the '?' that I added to your expression, that makes the space optional (use * instead for 0 or more spaces)

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
(V|H|v|h)\s*(-|–)\s*
```

the \s* gives you the options whitespace

also if you want to find multiple use /g

Comment: You're missing the start-of-string `^`, and you can use `/i` instead of listing both cases.

Answer (score 1):

The regex can be simplified:

alert(str.replace(/^[VN]\s*[-–]\s*/i, 'replaced'));

You had expressions like `(V|N)`, but the alternation group is unnecessary when it's single characters. It's equivalent to `[VN]`, which indicates all the possible matches for a single character.